# LESS -webkit-image-set Bug

Tags: css, less

When I try to compile the following code, LESS automatically add in a space before `x`, couldnt find a way to remove it. very frustrating.

LESS:

```css
background-image: -webkit-image-set(url(images/press-coverage-1x.png) 1x, url(images/press-coverage-2x.png) 2x;
```

CSS:

```css
background-image: -webkit-image-set(url(images/press-coverage-1x.png) 1 x, url(images/press-coverage-2x.png) 2 x;
```

**notice the spaces between "1" [space] "x", and "2" [space] "x"**

had tried:

LESS:

```css
background-image: -webkit-image-set(url(images/press-coverage-1x.png) ~"1x", url(images/press-coverage-2x.png) ~"2x";

background-image: ~"-webkit-image-set(url(images/press-coverage-1x.png) 1x, url(images/press-coverage-2x.png) 2x";

background-image: e("-webkit-image-set(url(images/press-coverage-1x.png) 1x, url(images/press-coverage-2x.png) 2x");

background-image: %("-webkit-image-set(url(images/press-coverage-1x.png) %s, url(images/press-coverage-2x.png) %s)", "1x", "2x");
```

All of the above couldnt make it work, the closest one is the last one, however, it added quoutes around the String, which still will not work.

Thanks a lot for your time!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works properly with Less 1.7.0. You can test it here http://lesstester.com/ (uses Less 1.7.0). Paste the code below. You'll see that it doesn't add any spaces:

```
.sec-1 {
  background-image-1: -webkit-image-set(url(images/press-coverage-1x.png) ~"1x", url(images/press-coverage-2x.png) ~"2x");
  background-image-2: ~"-webkit-image-set(url(images/press-coverage-1x.png) 1x, url(images/press-coverage-2x.png) 2x";
  background-image-3: e("-webkit-image-set(url(images/press-coverage-1x.png) 1x, url(images/press-coverage-2x.png) 2x");
  background-image-4: %(~"-webkit-image-set(url(images/press-coverage-1x.png) %s, url(images/press-coverage-2x.png) %s)", "1x", "2x");
}
```

It generates:

```
.sec-1 {
  background-image-1: -webkit-image-set(url(images/press-coverage-1x.png) 1x, url(images/press-coverage-2x.png) 2x);
  background-image-2: -webkit-image-set(url(images/press-coverage-1x.png) 1x, url(images/press-coverage-2x.png) 2x;
  background-image-3: -webkit-image-set(url(images/press-coverage-1x.png) 1x, url(images/press-coverage-2x.png) 2x;
  background-image-4: -webkit-image-set(url(images/press-coverage-1x.png) 1x, url(images/press-coverage-2x.png) 2x);
}
```

As for the last one, you can always a tilde before a string to remove the quotes from the CSS.

If for some reason you can't upgrade to a newer version of Less, you might perhaps try variables, interpolated or not:

```
@x1: 1x;
@x2: 2x;

.sec-1 {
  background-image-1: -webkit-image-set(url(images/press-coverage-1x.png) @x1, url(images/press-coverage-2x.png) @x2);
  background-image-2: ~'-webkit-image-set(url(images/press-coverage-1x.png) @{x1}, url(images/press-coverage-2x.png) @{x2})';
  background-image-3: -webkit-image-set(~'url(images/press-coverage-1x.png) @{x1}, url(images/press-coverage-2x.png) @{x2}');
}
```